# Which parameters decide Windows App OS requirements?

Tags: windows-10-universal, windows

If you try to get an app from Windows App Store, in System Requirements there is OS build number. Which says something like 'Windows 10 version 14393.0 or higher is required'. Who decides this? As a developer I have not coded anything OS specific. I want to make my app work in OS having lower version than this, what should I do?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a universal windows application project visual studio show you a box like below to set your **Target Version** and **Minimum Version** of windows which your project run on it.

[image]

You can also change your project *Target Version* and *Minimum Version* when your app had been created, to do that go to **project Properties** , in **Application tab** on the **Targeting** section change your target and minimum version.

Comment: I am not using visual studio but I was able to find targetVersion and MinVersion in the manifest file. Thanks.